# OpenResty: Is it possible to create a ngx.shared.DICT in Lua without using a directive?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm currently writing some tests for an existing [OpenResty](https://openresty.org) application. It uses some shared dictionaries, which are created in the nginx.conf file via the [lua_shared_dict](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#lua_shared_dict) directive.

I could write my own mock implementation for it, but I wonder if it is possible to programmatically create an [ngx.shared.DICT](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxshareddict) object?

Is it possible to create it within Lua, or is it better to create a mock implementation yourself?

---

*Background: My current test setup is quite easy. I use [busted](http://olivinelabs.com/busted/) as a  test framework and run it from the command line with the `resty` binary. The idea comes from [this article](http://ywebdev.com/?p=56).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a programmatic way to create the shared dictionaries, so I ended up mocking it:

```
ngx.shared.someDict = {}
ngx.shared.someDict.get = function(self, key)
  return ngx.shared.someDict[key]
end
ngx.shared.someDict.set = function(self, key, val)
  ngx.shared.someDict[key] = val
end
```

Comment: Does this preserves other shared dict behaviors ? like is it consistent after reload ? is it shared amongst other nginx workers ? have you tested this?

Comment: @Mercury As written in the question, I was using that mock setup within unit tests. So, it is not intended to be used in a productive environment with multiple workers. In the context of unit testing, it was sufficient for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

ngx.shared.DICT is ngx_shm_zone_t which used by nginx to share memory between process. accross to [nginx guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#shared_memory) , shared memory allocated when configuation parsed, So it may not possible to initialize in lua code. especially, ngx.shared.DICT is used to share memory between process. when worker has initilized, It's not possible to allocate memory shared with parent process by mmap call.